# Git: Modify content of a commit in history

Tags: git

From some reasons I'd like to change content of a commit.
I've got:

```
A --- B --- C     master

git co -b modify_old_commit B
git add ...
git ci ...
```

And at the end I've got:

```
A --- B --- C      master
       \
        \
         B' modify_old_commit

A --- B' ---- C     master
```

How can I "merge" B' with B? Is it possible? At the end I don't need branch modify_old_commit.

Answer (score 1):

You can reach the result you want by doing:

```
git checkout master
git rebase modify_old_commit
git branch -d modify_old_commit
```

You'll end up with

```
A --- B' ---- C'     master
```

where `C'` is modified to sit on top of `B'` instead of on `B`.

Comment: But this also modify further commits. And I want change only one commit.
For example, someone forgot append some text or a file. But this content won't be in further commits. I know that is strange.

Comment: @piecia Yes. In Git, a commit always depends on all previous commits. This is by design.